# IPRange IPv6 and cidrs()

Tags: python, ipv6

I'm noticing an issue with the cidrs() method for IPRange in netaddr when using IPv6.

If I define a smaller IPv6 range it works correctly:

```
r1=IPRange('1fe::2','1fe::100')
r1.cidrs()
[IPNetwork('1fe::2/127'), IPNetwork('1fe::4/126'), IPNetwork('1fe::8/125'), IPNetwork('1fe::10/124'), IPNetwork('1fe::20/123'), IPNetwork('1fe::40/122'), IPNetwork('1fe::80/121'), IPNetwork('1fe::100/128')]
```

If I define a large Range set I receive a traceback:

```
r1=IPRange('1fe::2','2fe::1')
r1.cidrs()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netaddr/ip/__init__.py", line 1337, 
in cidrs
return iprange_to_cidrs(self._start, self._end)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/netaddr/ip/__init__.py", line 1798, 
in iprange_to_cidrs
cidr_remainder = cidr_exclude(cidr_list.pop(), ip)
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

Does anyone know if this is a limitation or a bug in cidrs() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/drkjam/netaddr/pull/56) in version `0.7.10` of netaddr that's fixed in version [`0.7.11`](http://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#release-0-7-11).  All subsequent versions seem to work as expected for the IP range in your example.